# Combinatorial interpretation of a pfaffian identity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, pfaffian

Let $n$ be a positive even integer. We introduce three types of skew-symmetric matrices, $A_{n+2}$, $B_n$ and $C_n$ (the subscript denotes the dimension of the matrices)
in terms of the variables $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_{n+2}$. The off-diagonal elements are given by
$$
(A_{n+2})_{i,j} = \frac{1}{z_i-z_j}\ , \\
(B_{n})_{i,j} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(z_i-z_{n+1})^2(z_j-z_{n+2})^2+(z_i-z_{n+2})^2(z_j-z_{n+1})^2)}{z_i-z_j}\ , \\
(C_{n})_{i,j} = \frac{(z_i-z_{n+1})(z_i-z_{n+2})(z_j-z_{n+1})(z_j-z_{n+2})}{z_i-z_j} \ .
$$

One then has the following identity of symmetric polynomials
$$
\rm{Pf} (A_{n+2}) \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n+2}(z_i-z_j)=
\Bigl( 
2\,\rm{Pf} (B_{n}) - \rm{Pf} (C_{n}) 
\Bigr)
\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n}(z_i-z_j)
\ .
$$
This identity was obtained in a rather roundabout way using (the Ising) conformal field theory. One can also prove this identity by induction, which is not very enlightening.

I would like to know if there is a more interesting combinatorial derivation or interpretation of this identity.